# Apply $v=\ln u$ and then $v(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$ to solve the PDE $x^2u_x^2+y^2u_y^2=(xyu)^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Apply $v=\ln u$ and then $v(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$ to solve the PDE
> $$x^2u_x^2+y^2u_y^2=(xyu)^2.$$

**Attempt**: From  $v=\ln u$, we have $u_x=u v_x$, $u_y=uv_y$.

Then  $x^2u_x^2+y^2u_y^2=(xyu)^2$ reduces to
$$x^2v_x^2+y^2v_y^2=x^2y^2, \text{ i.e. }\ \ \ x^2(f'(x))^2+y^2 (g'(y))^2=x^2y^2.$$

But I am unable to proceed further as I am unable to separate the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the choice $v = \ln u$ we assumed that $u>0$.

Continuing from
$$x^2(f'(x))^2+y^2 (g'(y))^2=x^2y^2,$$
the above holds for all $x, y$. Choose $y=0$ gives

$$ x^2 (f'(x))^2 = 0,$$

thus $f$ is constant. Similarly by plugging $x=0$, $g$ is also constant. Thus $u$ has to be a constant function. Thus $u_x = u_y = 0$. Put this back to the original equation, we find that $u = 0$..... which is contradictory to the assumption that $u>0$. So it seems that your method can't be used to solve this PDE.

Going back to the original PDE,
$$\tag{1} x^2u_x^2+y^2u_y^2=(xyu)^2,$$
let's try $u(x, y) = h(xy)$ for some function $h = h(t)$. Then
$$ u_x (x, y) = y h'(xy), \  \ \ \ u_y(x, y) = xh'(xy),$$
thus (1) implies
$$ 2(h'(xy))^2 = h^2(xy)\Rightarrow h'(t) = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} h(t)$$
which gives
$$h(t) = C e^{ \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} t}$$

and thus

$$ u(x, y) = Ce^{\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} xy}.$$